# How to update manual page in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: updates, update-manager

I was planning to view manual page for 'ip' command for usage on 'ip tuntap'. To my surprise, there was no 'tuntap' pattern in that manual page. However 'ip tuntap' is well-supported when I try to use that command.

So I guess that my local manual page for 'ip' is outdate and need to be upgraded. I know that some manual pages can be installed by 'apt-get install XXX-doc'. But how can I upgrade the manual for 'ip'?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, the `ip` subcommand `tuntap` is described in `man ip` under 14.04 Trusty, but not under 12.04 Precise.

If the command itself in the latest repository version for Precise does indeed support `ip tuntap`, the missing description is a bug that should be reported for the package `iproute2`.

The man page is in the main package, `iproute2`. The package `iproute2-doc` does exist, but is an empty transitional package, with dependency on `iproute2`.

I do not know how to best get a package installed with an updated man page - it may not be easy, because the software is in the same package.

But you can get the man page versions of the Ubuntu releases online at http://manpages.ubuntu.com - for example [man ip for Precise](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/ip.8.html) and [man ip for Trusty](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/ip.8.html).

Comment: I see. I'll try to update my Ubuntu to 14.04 Trusty and view the online version document as well if that is not enough. But....very sorry that I cannot '+1' for your answer because my reputation is less than 15.... Really thanks for your answer!